# Enabling HTTP gzip compression in Azure IIS

Tags: .net, http, azure-web-app-service, http-compression, appveyor

I need to enable gzip compression on a Azure deployment

I tried with:

```
   <httpCompression directory="">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll=""/>
    <dynamicTypes>
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true"/>
    </staticTypes>
  </httpCompression>
```

but how I should set the temporary and DLL folders?